# Allow users to login with Active Directory Accounts

Tags: login

I have a raspberry pi that i would like to login to using our Windows Active Directory accounts.

I followed the instructions on this link:
https://www.techgeeks.org/blog/2015/07/13/raspberry-pi-ldap-authentication/

But when I switch over to my account name:
su mySAMAccountName

It doesn't recognize the user and gives me No passwd entry for user 'mySAMAccountName'

Comment: Do you follow one of the answers? Does it help you? If so it would be nice if accept one answer. This will finish your question and it will not pop up again.

Answer (score 1):

Active directory uses Samba for networking, so you'll have to install and configure it, and replace `ldap` with `winbind` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to use it. You will likely not need `nslcd`.

Check out [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Active_Directory_Integration) wiki page (for Arch) to have an overview of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial you have linked I only see that it authenticate against OpenLDAP. Of course both use *kerberos* But Active Directory is not OpenLDAP. Microsoft does not respect open standards and it is known that there are some quirks as usual. You have to look for specific tutorials that address this problem. After a quick search for example I found this one: [Integrate Active Directory and OpenLDAP](https://www.itprotoday.com/active-directory/integrate-active-directory-and-openldap) using a special proxy service but I don't know if there are better ones.